# String.Insert not working

Tags: c#, xna

I have (hopefully) a simple problem.

```
String.Insert(0, "test");
```

is not working, yet:

```
String.Text += "test";
```

does..? I need Insert so I can insert something in the middle of a string.

Comment: Have you tried seeing what `String.Insert(0, "test")` returns? Since strings are immutable in .Net you get back a new string.

Comment: Yes just realized after a search, I'm so idiotic! Thank you though!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm such an idiot, instant Google search fixed this.

String.Insert does not modify the string it is called on, but instead returns a new string with the inserted text in.

So I needed:

```
String = String.Insert(0, "test");
```

Comment: Is your `string` actually named `String`? You should probably change that as `String` is a class already.

Comment: string is keyword to represent the string variables..your string name should be changed..see my answer

Comment: using String as the name was just for example.

Comment: @DeanReynolds I think you should accept Sachu's answer and remove your own answer.

Comment: @DeanReynolds you shouldn't use `String` as a name even in an example.

Answer (score 5):

it should work

see the below example

```
string names = "Romeo Juliet";
string shakespeare = names.Insert(6, "and ");

Console.WriteLine(shakespeare);
```

the result will be Romeo and Juliet

[see the fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AV2vw4)